# Cannot Get Automated Tests to Run in YAML using Azure

Tags: c#, azure, automation, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am trying to run some automated tests as part of a build pipeline but I keep getting no results returned. My test files generally look like "ApiTests" or "UITests". I am trying to target them by finding the "Tests" part of the file. However, I keep getting this message in the automated test runner: **Test run detected DLL(s) which were built for different framework and platform versions. Following DLL(s) do not match current settings, which are .NETFramework,Version=v4.0 framework and X86 platform.**
My version according to the csproj file is 3.1.
Here is what the YAML is looking like currently:

```
# ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting the full .NET Framework.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
  inputs:
    version: 3.0.x
    performMultiLevelLookup: true
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    msbuildArchitecture: 'x64'

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Automated Tests' 
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*test*.dll
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    testFiltercriteria: '/Tests:Tests'
    uiTests: true
    runTestsInIsolation: true
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

My files are generally named like: AppsSigninTests.cs

And my actual tests kind of look like this:

```
[Fact]
        public void SomethingSomethingSomething()
        {
            //Test Code Here
        }
```

Should I add "Test" to the end of my test titles? What am I missing that is making the YAML miss these tests?

***EDIT***
I am to a point now where it is finding the file but not running the actual test (still showing no results). Here is the YAML now:

```
# ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting the full .NET Framework.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

#- task: UseDotNet@2
  #displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
  #inputs:
    #version: 3.0.x
    #performMultiLevelLookup: true

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Automated Tests' 
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      AutomatedRegression.csproj
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
#**\*test*.dll
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    testFiltercriteria: '/Tests:VerySpecificNameOfTest'
    uiTests: true
    runTestsInIsolation: true
    codeCoverageEnabled: true
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

The test.dll line seems to make it so the yaml can't find the file(s) I'm after. But I am worried it is preventing the test from actually running. The output on the VSTest task has this: *A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.* but later it says this: *Publishing test results: 0*
And then the Tests tab after the run has no results and no tests run

Comment: Does your test project target .net core? From the message, sounds like it targets .net framework.

Comment: @Connell.O'Donnell it looks like it targets .net framework, should it be targetting .net code?

Comment: What is the value of `$(buildPlatform)`? If it's x64, why not try x86.

Comment: @Connell.O'Donnell it is currently "Any CPU" changed it to x86. Now I am getting this issue: 
    ##[warning]No test sources found matching the given filter 
    '**\*test*.dll,!**\*TestAdapter.dll,!**\obj\**'

Comment: For debugging this, I recommend adding a powershell task to tell you if the test results file exists at all, and what it contains. You can remove the task later.